# how to load loading indicator for Default.png image

Tags: objective-c, ipad

When application launch IOS automatically calling Default.png image to my application.

How to show loading indicator on top of Default.png image.

Answer (score 0):

Using UIActivityIndicatorView or UIProgressView.

Answer (score 0):

The Default.png image is displayed until you have the control and your code is reached. You can't change this.

Comment: So I can not show loading indicator for my default image.. when the application launches

Comment: No, at least you can, if your app needs a loading process, present Default.png in a way it simulates the loading screen, with progress bar empty, and when the app has finished launching, present a view that will, this time, really load something